# Deleting symlink created by NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject

Tags: windows, winapi, nt-native-api

`NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject` creates an object in the Windows Object Manager (you can see such links using the WinObj utility from System Internals).

What is the correct way to delete a symbolic link object? I noticed that using `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject` it is possible to specify `DELETE` in the `ACCESS_MASK` (bit 16 only) for delete access, but what I need to know is how to actually do the deletion?

Answer (score 2):

To delete a native object namespace symbolic link from user mode: build an OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES struct describing the link object, then:

```
...
if (NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject( &handle, DELETE, &objectAttributes) == STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    NtMakeTemporaryObject( handle);
    NtClose( handle);
}
```

You will likely need to use function pointers and GetProcAddress() for the NT*() function calls, unless you can track down or build an ntdll.dll import library to link against.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't actually specify if you're asking for user mode or kernel mode. My guess is, since you're *also* specifying the [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi), that you're looking for a solution in user mode. To my best knowledge there is no such functionality exposed from `ntdll.dll`. And frankly I've never even wondered why. So: good question!

Since the [nt-native-api](/questions/tagged/nt-native-api) is undocumented by definition, with the exception of those few functions and types in `winternl.h` in newer Windows SDKs, those shared between user and kernel mode (mostly `Rtl*`, `Nt*` and `Zw*`) documented in the WDKs and the many efforts to document them anyway (ReactOS, [this site](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/), the Process Hacker source code, WINE and so on), only Microsoft can give you a truly definite answer. But even they'd probably ask you to specify a particular Windows version.

However, we can still make a best guess based on available information.

On my Windows 7 x64 I can see the following (compare to `dumpbin /exports ntoskrnl.exe|findstr /i Symbolic`):

```
C:\Windows\System32>dumpbin /exports ntdll.dll|findstr /i Symbolic
        266   FB 000208BC NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject = _ZwCreateSymbolicLinkObject@16
        379  16C 00021150 NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject = _ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject@12
        440  1A9 00021588 NtQuerySymbolicLinkObject = _ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject@12
       1517  5E4 000208BC ZwCreateSymbolicLinkObject = _ZwCreateSymbolicLinkObject@16
       1628  653 00021150 ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject = _ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject@12
       1689  690 00021588 ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject = _ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject@12
```

So for user mode we seem indeed to be out of luck here. `ntdll.dll` is -- to my best knowledge -- our only way to access the NT native API from user mode (not counting the use of the system call dispatcher directly, which is impractical for all but a few specialized use cases) and there is no function at all that fits the bill.

However, *if* your question happens to have been asked for kernel mode, then -- as a driver developer -- I can happily point you to: [`IoDeleteSymbolicLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iodeletesymboliclink) which is paired with [`IoCreateSymbolicLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreatesymboliclink) (and [`IoCreateUnprotectedSymbolicLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iocreateunprotectedsymboliclink)) and *not* with `NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject` (or `ZwCreateSymbolicLinkObject`) inside `DriverEntry`. As you can tell from the documentation it's pretty trivial to create a symbolic link object from a driver and remove it again, using the I/O manager's functions.

PS: You may want to take a peek at the ReactOS sources `obname.c`, `oblink.c` (both `ob`) and `symlink.c` (`io/iomgr`) seem to be good candidates. Typically you can get a relatively faithful glimpse of how Windows would implement this. But there *are* differences and ReactOS is kind of a moving target given that they have in the past changed the Windows version they target for compatibility. Besides, behavior of those functions can and will change between Windows versions (and even service packs) as well.