# NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject doesn't succeed to get symbolic link handle

Tags: c#, winapi, symlink, junction, nt-native-api

I am trying to remove a symbolic link that I created.
You can see it in the Object manager (WinObj):
[image]

I am trying to delete the folder. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63567810/2153777) that I need to open a handle to object with `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject` and then use `NtMakeTemporaryObject` to delete it.

I tried to do it with number of different calls to `DeleteSymbolicLink`, and the function `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject` doesn't succeed to get handle. Here is the code I used:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern int NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject(
out SafeFileHandle LinkHandle,
uint DesiredAccess,
ref ObjectAttributes ObjectAttributes);

public enum NtStatus : uint
{
    Success = 0x00000000
}

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern NtStatus NtMakeTemporaryObject(SafeFileHandle Handle);


[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
static extern int NtClose(SafeFileHandle handle);

public static void DeleteSymbolicLink(SafeKernelObjectHandle directory, string path){
    uint DELETE = 0x00010000;
    SafeFileHandle handle;
    ObjectAttributes obja = new ObjectAttributes(path, AttributeFlags.CaseInsensitive, directory, null, null);

    if (NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject( out handle, DELETE, ref obja) == 0x00000000)
    {
        NtMakeTemporaryObject( handle);
        NtClose( handle);
    }
}

public static void CreateSymlink(string inputPath, string outPath)
{
    string inputFilename = Path.GetFileName(inputPath);
    string inputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(inputPath);

    JunctionPoint.Create(@"\RPC Control", inputDir, true);
    CreateSymbolicLink(null, @"\RPC Control\" + inputFilename, outPath);
}

static SafeKernelObjectHandle CreateSymbolicLink(SafeKernelObjectHandle directory, string path, string target)
{

    using (ObjectAttributes obja = new ObjectAttributes(path, AttributeFlags.CaseInsensitive, directory, null, null))
    {
        IntPtr handle;
        StatusToNtException(NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject(out handle, GenericAccessRights.MaximumAllowed, obja, new UnicodeString(target)));
        return new SafeKernelObjectHandle(handle, true);
    }
}



static void Main(string[] args){
    CreateSymlink("C:\tmp\MyFile.txt", fileToDelete);
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, @"\RPC Control\" + "\??\C:\Windows\win2.ini");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, @"\RPC Control\" + "MyFile.txt");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, @"\RPC Control\" + "C:\tmp\MyFile.txt");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, "MyFile.txt");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, "C:\tmp\MyFile.txt");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, "\??\C:\Windows\win2.ini");
}
```

Comment: `CreateSymbolicLink` sets a reparse point on a file or directory via `FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT`, this is nothing common at all with `SymbolicLink` object

Comment: But after the call to `CreateSymbolicLink` it creates the `SymbolicLink` object in the object manager (see the picture)

Comment: `CreateSymbolicLink` not create `SymbolicLink` of course

Comment: `NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject` call create `SymbolicLink`, for delete it you need just close returned handle

Comment: `NtMakeTemporaryObject` have effect only on permanent object, but you noy use `OBJ_PERMANENT` attribute on create or call `NtMakePermanentObject` (and you not have `SeCreatePermanentPrivilege` privilege - so call senseless

Comment: Cool, it works. I changed the `CreateSymlink` to return the handle, closed it and not it has been removed. Submit it as an answer and I will mark it as completed. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @RbMm I used the CreateSymlink tool with the `-p` switch to create permanent link, but this is a different question so I opened new ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378857/how-to-delete-permanent-symbolic-link-in-windows  . I don't  know how to delete the permanent link.