# How to delete permanent symbolic link in Windows?

Tags: c#, winapi, symlink

I used [CreateSymlink](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/blob/main/CreateSymlink/CreateSymlink.cpp) tool with the `-p` switch to create a **permanent** symbolic link.

I am not able to delete this object although I succeeded to delete the folder. I can still view it through the [WinObj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) utility.
I saw [here](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/blob/00c0fe4cefcd2a62c887fe6117abc02bc98bb9fb/CommonUtils/FileSymlink.cpp#L173-L181) that it adds `Global\\GLOBALROOT` to the string but I also tried to delete it with this prefix without success.

This is how the tool creates the permanent link:

```
static bool CreatePermanentSymlink(LPCWSTR symlink, LPCWSTR target)
{
    if (DefineDosDevice(DDD_NO_BROADCAST_SYSTEM | DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH, symlink, target) 
        && DefineDosDevice(DDD_NO_BROADCAST_SYSTEM | DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH, symlink, target))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I don't understand how to delete it.
I tried to delete it using the `NtMakeTemporaryObject` function but without success. Maybe I have mistake in my code?

My code:

```
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern int NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject(
out SafeFileHandle LinkHandle,
uint DesiredAccess,
ref ObjectAttributes ObjectAttributes);

public enum NtStatus : uint
{
    Success = 0x00000000
}

[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern NtStatus NtMakeTemporaryObject(SafeFileHandle Handle);


[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
static extern int NtClose(SafeFileHandle handle);

public static void DeleteSymbolicLink(SafeKernelObjectHandle directory, string path){
    uint DELETE = 0x00010000;
    SafeFileHandle handle;
    ObjectAttributes obja = new ObjectAttributes(path, AttributeFlags.CaseInsensitive, directory, null, null);

    if (NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject( out handle, DELETE, ref obja) == 0x00000000)
    {
        NtMakeTemporaryObject( handle);
        NtClose( handle);
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args){
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, @"\RPC Control\MyFile.txt");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, @"\Global\GLOBALROOT\C:\tmp\MyFile.txt");
    DeleteSymbolicLink(null, @"Global\GLOBALROOT\C:\tmp\MyFile.txt");
}
```

Comment: you confuse 2 absolute different objects - file system reparse points and symboliclinks. you need first determinate what you try todo and difference between this

Comment: I tried to create a symbolic link and it worked for me with the tool but I used the `-p` switch so now it is a "permanent" symbolic link as I understand from the tool. I didn't see that it specify something about reparse points.

Comment: you even not try check and post ntstatus code from api. you not try got `SeCreatePermanentPrivilege` first which is **mandatory**

Comment: @RbMm yes you right! Sorry, I will do it and update.

Comment: @RbMm All my three delete attempts failed because of `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject` returns error as int: `-1073741811` which is `FFFF FFFF C000 000D` in hex. I don't think it is a valid error code. When I searched for only `0xC000000D`, it looks like a boot error other people received. Not sure how it is related to our case.

Comment: 0xC000000D is `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Why not just call RemovePermanentSymlink?

Comment: @RaymondChen saw it now, I am trying it.

Comment: I called `DefineDosDevice(DDD_NO_BROADCAST_SYSTEM | DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH | DDD_REMOVE_DEFINITION | DDD_EXACT_MATCH_ON_REMOVE, @"\RPC Control\MyFile.txt", fileToWrite);` but it still doesn't work. Maybe the device name is wrong. Although I tried with `\Rpc Control`  and   `Global\GlobalRoot` and `\Global\GlobalRoot\Rpc Control`.

Comment: I am pretty sure the device should be `\RPC Control\MyFile`, this is how it appear in the WinObj utility.

Comment: if `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` probably you wrong init `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`

Comment: @RbMm "Normally to create a permanent named kernel object you need the SeCreatePermanentPrivilege privilege, however a normal user does not have that privilege. On the other hand CSRSS does, so by calling into that service we can create the permanent symbolic link." from https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/08/windows-exploitation-tricks-exploiting.html

Comment: @RbMm tnx, I think the correct way to remove it is using the `DefineDosDevice` but I still didn't find the correct way to use it. Still trying to understand how to pass it with the correct `symlink` and `target` variables like the author of the tool did.

Comment: i know that normal user does not have that privilege, but if you have `SeDebugPrivilege` you can open process and it token where exist `SeCreatePermanentPrivilege`